# How to implement native code to autofill the OTP Text Field in iOS?

Tags: ios, flutter, cross-platform

I'm trying to implement a flutter plugin which can help autofill a text field in iOS.

According to [iOS developer docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/password_autofill/enabling_password_autofill_on_a_text_input_view), I need to set the  `UITextContentType`  as `UITextContentType.oneTimeCode`, if I am creating a native iOS App.

Is there a way to set this property ( `UITextContentType.oneTimeCode`) for the flutter text field, so that iOS can recognise it as such?

Answer (score 0):

Flutter supports autofill now on stable channel :) <strike>You may need to upgrade to `dev` or `master` channel (`flutter channel master`).</strike>

You can add `autofillHints: const <String>[AutofillHints.oneTimeCode]` to your textfield.

The docs on the stable channel have not yet been updated. See the master channel docs below.
https://master-api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/AutofillHints/oneTimeCode-constant.html